# How does Angularjs handle Memory Management with ngView?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

When you are using ngView with say 100 different views each with a different scope. Does Angular automatically handle destroying the old templates/scopes or do they stay in memory? I'm just curious if Angular handles this by itself before I go and start writing custom code to reduce the memory load. As of right now each new view I go to just stacks up in the memory.

This is an AngularJS specific question. I know how garbage collection works in javascript.

Comment: Yes, js has garbage collection. But it will not collect anything that it believes to be in use. With angular it assumes that the $scopes are still in use, therefore it will never collect it. So I'm asking how to what do I need to do in Angular to make sure it can be collected.

Comment: You could always use "delete"?

Comment: @KGChristensen That's not how `delete` works?

Comment: @rounce No, it's not as I later learned :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One of the design decisions behind introducing scopes was to ease memory management. By partitioning model's space into sub-parts (scopes) we can remove unneeded parts of the model (scope) and add new when needed. So yes, scopes are important part of the whole memory-management puzzle.

When it comes to your specific question about `ng-view` - this directive will keep scope only for the *currently active view*. `ng-view` is one of the scope creating (and scope destroying!) directives. It will automatically create a new scope when a new view is navigated to and will automatically destroy a scope connected with the old view. This can be easily verified in the AngularJS [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/7a5cfb593f27c28cee545974736632bf8da62fe8/src/ng/directive/ngView.js#L179).

The only memory-consuming part to consider are templates fetched over a network. All the templates referenced in a route are cached in the [`$templateCache`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24templateCache). You could evict templates using sparingly if you determine that it tackles a specific perf bottleneck in your app. We just need to realize that it is trading time (network time) for memory consumption.

In short: no need to roll out your own scope-management for the `ng-view` - if you see any scope retention it should be reported as a bug.

Comment: What about the html of the template? I know it is keeping that because it never does another ajax request for the template?

Comment: Yes, all the fetched templates are put into `$templateCache`: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache You could evict those on route change event. Updated the answer.

Comment: hi @pkozlowski.opensource what about the user defined directives which creates isolated scopes?